# api call in a loop until response is success

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I'm trying to do a rest API call from my nodejs script. I want the script to keep repeating the call for this api until I get a positive result. 
here's what I'm trying to do but my script simply freezes:

```
var success=0;

while(!success){

  axios.post('http://localhost:2000/evaluate', {serviceName:"s1"})
       .then((response)=>{
          if(response.data==1){
            success=1; //desired response, quit the loop
            res.send('1')
          }
          else{ //not the desired response, keep trying
            res.send('0') 
          }

}//end while loop
```

Basically, how can I make a repeated API calls until I get the response I want??

Thanks!

Comment: Just use a setInterval

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace `success` with a retry counter and call the function again if necessary from with the callback. Also keep a counter to not find yourself in an endless loop if anything goes wrong.

```
// your callback gets executed automatically once the data is received
var callback = (data, error) => {
    // consume data
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return;
    }
    console.log(data);
};

// run the request. this function will call itself max. 5 times if the request fails
request(5, callback);

function request(var retries, var callback) {
    axios.post('http://localhost:2000/evaluate', {
        serviceName:"s1"
    }).then(response => {
        // request successful

        if(response.data['done'] == 1) {
            // server done, deliver data to script to consume
            callback(response);
        }
        else {
            // server not done yet
            // retry, if any retries left
            if (retries > 0) {
                request(--retries, callback);
            }
            else {
                // no retries left, calling callback with error
                callback([], "out of retries");
            }
        }
    }).catch(error => {
        // ajax error occurred
        // would be better to not retry on 404, 500 and other unrecoverable HTTP errors
        // retry, if any retries left
        if (retries > 0) {
            request(--retries, callback);
        }
        else {
            // no retries left, calling callback with error
            callback([], error);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This is great!, just one question..How would the request function pass on data to another function if needed.. i mean instead of res.send(), suppose I had to return the value to another function later in the script.

Comment: You might also want to consider waiting between retries so as not to overload the server (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/api-retries.html)

Comment: Thats a really good idea!

Comment: @anuragb26 that is the asynchronous nature. You cannot return to the function. You must think of it as the request being done immediately and the response will happen at a later point. Your code shouldn't wait for the response but continue running and consume the data and act accordingly in a callback. It's a bit hard to wrap your head around the concept at first, but once you got it it's fun to use :)

Comment: @anuragb26 I added some information, I hope it helps you understand :)

Comment: Got It!.This helps me in clearing out the dilemna I used to have about when to use promises vs callbacks..the addition of callback really helped..Thanks a ton Julian !!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad I could help! Please remember to accept correct answers and welcome to SO  :)

Comment: @Julian F. Weinert, thank you for your answer. I don't understand how your code is calling the api more than once and where i can check the result for the call. would you please clarify?

Comment: The ajax response handler determines wether or not the request was successful. If the request was *not* successful, the handler calls the request function again from within itself. The result gets delivered to you. The response callback passed to the original request call gets executed automatically once the request is done. Consume the data inside there

Comment: I added some info once again! If that doesn't help, please try a tutorial *video* on asynchronousity (not a real word) to get the basic concept, I don't know how to better explain it in written word (I'm not a native english speaker). I really want you to get it... 